# How do I search for a list of user id's using LDAP and C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, directorysearcher

I need to search for users given a specific list of User ID's. It works fine if I use this filter to search for a single user:

```
 using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de) { Filter = $"(&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(sAMAccountName=xyz123))" })
 {
    SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
 }
```

I found this [LDAP Filter Syntax page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) and it shows that conditions can be nested.

> (|(cn=Jim Smith)(&(givenName=Jim)(sn=Smith)))
>
> Conditions can be nested with parentheses, but make sure the
>   parentheses match up.

So I tried using this filter and FindAll() and while I expected to see 1 for us and 1 for canada, it only found the one in canada.

> (&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(!(sAMAccountName=xyz123)(sAMAccountName=abc456)))
>
> Searching domain: us
>
> Count: 0
>
> Searching domain: canada
>
> Count: 1

So maybe I'm not understanding the filter syntax well enough. Also, is it possible to search all domains with one call?

Comment: You have an ! in your syntax, not an OR (|)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an exclamation mark (`!`), which means "not". You want to use a pipe (`|`), which means "or":

```
(&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(|(sAMAccountName=xyz123)(sAMAccountName=abc456)))
```

If you have a large list of usernames that you're looking for (I'm talking hundreds), you might think of splitting them up into separate searches. I actually covered this (with sample code) in an article I wrote about this: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html#ask-for-as-much-as-you-can-at-a-time)

Comment: yeah.  I just figured that out...  it was a typo, not intentional.  I just didn't see it until I asked the question.  I'm just looking for a list of anywhere from 1 to 100 people max. depending on what is received from an sql query.  This app emails people who have alerts to view.